# EF Map The Latest Object In A List Of Objects

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, mapping

I am trying to do this `Linq` query:

```
dataContext.Request.Where(x => x.LatestResponse.IsReviewRequired);
```

The problem is that `LatestResponseID` is actually not a column on the `Request` table.

To get the `LatestResponse`, I have to do this `SQL`:

```
  SELECT ....
  FROM [doe].[Request] Req
      LEFT JOIN (
          SELECT MAX(ResponseID)
          FROM [doe].[Response]
          GROUP BY [RequestID]) AS Resp ON Req.[RequestID] = Resp.[RequestID]
      LEFT JOIN [doe].[Response] LatestResp ON Resp.[ResponseID] = LatestResp.[ResponseID]
```

Can I `map` this? If so, how?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this (if you want both sides of the join back):

```
var results = dataContext.Requests.Select(request => new
        {
            Request = request,
            LatestResponse = request .Responses.FirstOrDefault(response => response .RequestID == request.Responses.Max(response2 => response2.RequestID))
        });
```

Also, if you are trying to just get the request object back, but have it filtered by a property on the latest response, here is an example of that:

```
var results = dataContext.Requests.Select(request => new
        {
            Request = request,
            LatestResponse = request.Responses.FirstOrDefault(response => response.RequestID == request.Responses.Max(response2 => response2.RequestID))
        }).Where(request => request.LatestResponse.MyProperty == "Value").Select(request => request.Request);
```